# Why program size differs when it's gonna been installed on a different drive?

Tags: installation, path, disk-space

I have two drives installed on my pc: a 60 GB SSD drive for Windows 10 x64 and some desktop apps and a 128 GB HDD for Linux, storage and most of desktop apps (portable as well). 
I want to install a 3d modelling program (3Ds MAX) and I'm on the Autodesk 3D Max 2017 installation procedure right now. I'm looking forward to discover how much of space it would be occupy on my C:\ Drive (the SSD) and the Autodesk windows says 13,5 GB ->

[image: on SSD]

---

If I edit the path and select the D:\ drive (HDD) Autodesk window says it would occupy 2,69 GB only ->

[image: on HDD]

**Why do I get different sizes depending on which drive I choose to install the program?**

Comment: The only explanation is that it already has a few files on the D drive. and not on the C drive.

Comment: There are probably a good few components or dependencies that get installed on your C: drive irrespective of where you specify the "main" program install directory. Essentially all it is showing you is the install size on *that* drive rather than what is needed on *all* drives or other drives.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the screenshots, the installation path it is showing is only for `Program Data`; this is not the folder path where the core components of an application get installed. The application itself will still be installed in `C:\Program Files` folder regardless of which drive you choose as the installation path.

It took some digging to find a source from Autodesk to confirm this. 
In the Autodesk forums a Product Support Specialists replies the following to someone asking about basically your same issue (although the forum discussion is about the 2015 version):

> There is a certain amount of files that must reside on the "C"
>   partition to support user's profile and operating system information.

You can read the full Autodesk forum post [here.](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/out-of-disk-space-during-installation-to-another-disk-drive/td-p/3759083/page/3)